# Cannot instantiate mock objects using InjectMocks-Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

I'm new to TDD and mockito aswell, I'm trying to inject mocks into a class to perform a unit test, the class instantiate its dependencies inside a method depending on some validations, I got an error

test class/method

```
//Its interface 
public interface UserService {

    public Debt getCustomerDebt(String id);
}

//validator method

public static boolean isValidId(String id){
    if(id != null && !id.isEmpty() && !id.trim().equals("")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private Repository repo;
    private WSDLCustomerDebt wsdlCostumerDebt;

    public static final int USER_EXIST = 1;
    public static final int USER_DOESNOT_EXIST = 0;

    public UserServiceImpl(){

    }

    public Debt getCustomerDebt(String id) {

        if(ValidatorHelper.isValidId(id)){
            repo = new RepositoryImpl();
            int exist = repo.getCustomer(id);
            if(exist==USER_EXIST){
                wsdlCostumerDebt = new WSDLCustomerDebtImpl();
                List<Date> meses = wsdlCostumerDebt.obtenerMeses(id);
                if(meses.size()>0){
                    int totalDebt = 0;
                    for (Date mes : meses){
                        totalDebt += wsdlCostumerDebt.obtenerDeuda(mes, id);
                    }

                    return new Debt(id, BigDecimal.valueOf(totalDebt));

                }else{
                    return new Debt(id, BigDecimal.valueOf(0));
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

mocked class repositoryimpl

```
public class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {

    public int getCustomer(String id) {
        int y = Integer.valueOf(1);
        return y;
    }

}
```

wsdl mocked class

```
//Interface
public interface WSDLCustomerDebt {

    public List<Date> obtenerMeses(String customerId);

    public Integer obtenerDeuda(Date month, String customerId);

}

public class WSDLCustomerDebtImpl implements WSDLCustomerDebt {

    public List<Date> obtenerMeses(String customerId) {
        return null;
    }

    public Integer obtenerDeuda(Date month, String customerId) {
        Integer y = Integer.valueOf(11);
        return y;
    }
}
```

domain class debt

```
public class Debt {

    private String id;
    private BigDecimal debt;

    public Debt(String id, BigDecimal debt) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.debt = debt;
    }

    //Getters and setters ....
}
```

finally test class

```
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

public class UserServiceImplTest {
    @Mock
    private Repository repo;

    @Mock
    private WSDLCustomerDebt wsdlCustomerDebt;

    @InjectMocks
    private UserServiceImpl userService; 

    @Before
    public void init(){
        //repo=Mockito.mock(Repository.class);      
        //when(wsdlcustomer.obtenerDeuda(D, customerId))
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void noExistingCustomer(){
        //Given:
        String id = "123";
        //When:
        Mockito.when(repo.getCustomer(id)).thenReturn(0);
        Debt debt = userService.getCustomerDebt(id);
        Mockito.verify(repo.getCustomer(Mockito.any(String.class))); 
        //Then:
        assertNull(debt);   
    }
}
```

this is the error I'm getting and I'm trying to avoid using a constructor or any getter/setter and to receive the mocks via parameters, maybe it could be caused by a dummy error but at this point I do not know what I'm doing wrong, in fact i think the problem occurs because of the return statement in mocked classes. I'm using mockito version 1.9.5 btw

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() is of type Integer and is not a mock!
Make sure you place the parenthesis correctly!
See the examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
    at com.i2btech.poctest.UserServiceImplTest.noExistingCustomer(UserServiceImplTest.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your service doesn't use the mock you're injecting, since it creates a new one when you call the method. The repo should be an argument of the service constructor.

Second, the proper syntax to verify that a method of a mock has been called is not

```
verify(mock.method())
```

but

```
verify(mock).method()
```

(as the error message clearly says).

So, the line

```
Mockito.verify(repo.getCustomer(Mockito.any(String.class)))
```

must be replaced by

```
Mockito.verify(repo).getCustomer(Mockito.any(String.class))
```

Comment: the actual implementation of the method should perform the way i describe on the question, there is a way to achieve that? to initialize mocks without passing them like arguments? in the javadoc of injectmocks mention something about field injection with no constructor indicated, which is the best way to do that? some example?

Comment: You can avoid passing them as argument to the constructor (although it would be cleaner doing it). The point is that the method must NOT create its own instance of repo. The repo must be a field of the service.